# Connect Azure Search to Managed Instance SQL

Tags: sql, azure, instance, managed, azure-cognitive-search

Hello I am looking information on how to connect Azure Search Service to Managed Instance SQL on Azure

In other words

using the following for Managed instance in my indexer should work fine there is no difference btw implementing this for Azure SQL database and Azure SQL MI ?

```
    "name" : "myazuresqldatasource", 
    "type" : "azuresql", 
    "credentials" : { 
    "connectionString" : "Server=tcp:<your server>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<your database>;User ID=<your user name>;Password=<your password>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" }, 
"container" : { "name" : "name of the table" } –
```

Comment: Are you looking for a connection string?  Suggest you be more specific and include what you've tried so far - and make sure you've done a web search first.

Comment: I've had a go at making the code part more readable but it needs more work.  Your question is getting better, suggest you improve the question further by indicating how your attempt is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect your search service to managed SQL database by going through import data flow in Azure Portal:

[image]

Then in `Data source` section select `Azure SQL Database` and there you can either select existing (managed) database or choose to input connection string. You should do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

yes, he is looking for a connection string. His data source is SQL-MI because Microsoft has not provided any specific documentation if the connection string type will be the same if the data source is SQL or SQL MI. Actually, I am also unsure about that. Do I need to change my connection string type parameter if the source is SQL MI?

The Issues is resolve. If you want to connect to SQLMI the connection string should include database name. "Server=tcp:sqlmiservice.database.windows.net,{port};Database={name};User Id={Id};Password={pwd}".